# Performance issue. Views with kendo Ui grid take longer to load. Any suggestions?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

Scenario: I am using Kendo UI to my MVC application. I have created several partial views which contains Kendo Grid and renders these views in Index.cshtml page using Tabstrip. The sample code is as below. Application takes around 15-18 seconds first time launch. The network log (IE developer tool) suggest all these partial views methods takes around 1 second each. Any suggestion how can I improve the performance to load the application faster?

Main View - Index.cshtml

```
@(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
    .Name("Tabstrip_StrategyData")
    .Items(tabstrip =>
    {
        tabstrip.Add().Text("suppliers")
            .Content( @Html.Partial("Suppliers").ToHtmlString());
        tabstrip.Add().Text("Productions")
            .Selected(true)
            .Content(@Html.Partial("Productions").ToHtmlString());
        tabstrip.Add().Text("Sales")
            .Content(@Html.Partial("Sales").ToHtmlString());
    })
)
```

Controller methods

```
public ActionResult Suppliers_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        return Json(StrategyDataRepository.Suppliers_Read().ToDataSourceResult(request));
    }
public ActionResult Productions_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            return Json(StrategyDataRepository.Productions_Read().ToDataSourceResult(request));
        }
```

Repository methods

```
public IEnumerable<SuppliersViewModel> Suppliers_Read()
{
 IEnumerable<SuppliersViewModel> obj = (from sd in dbContext.StrategyData
                                        select new SuppliersViewModel
                                        {
                                          Id = sd.Id,                                                                   
                                          CountryName = sd.Name,
                                          LocationName = sd.LocationName,
                                         }).ToList();
            return obj;
        }

public IEnumerable<ProductionsViewModel> Productions_Read()
{
 IEnumerable<ProductionsViewModel> obj = (from sd in dbContext.StrategyData
                                          select new ProductionsViewModel
                                          { Id = sd.Id,                                                                    
                                            CountryName = sd.Name,
                                            LocationName = sd.LocationName,
                                          }).ToList();
            return obj;
        }
```

Any suggestion to improve the loading time?

Comment: ToDataSourceResult could be also executed on IQueryable object. In that case you will not have to compute all data in your IEnumerable object.(DataSourceRequest PageSize property will control portions of your data passed to grid).

Comment: Where is the Kendo Grid implementation? How much data is being loaded? Is it possible to utilise [`serverPaging`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-serverPaging) or [virtual scrolling](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/appearance#virtual-scrolling) to reduce the load (if data is a concern)? Are you doing any customisation to rows based on data i.e. through [`dataBound`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-dataBound) events?

Comment: These are very good suggestions for data management; However, not much data is being displayed (less then 100 records) in the grids at the moment. Grid implementation is simple without any customisation.